# Fetch numbers having only 2 types number

Tags: mysql

MySQL Database:

```
+-----------+
| Number    |
+-----------+
| 121255    |
+-----------+
| 22552525  |
+-----------+
| 122221221 |
+-----------+
| 555554    |
+-----------+
| 55445533  |
+-----------+
```

How to just fetch those numbers having any two number?
Here the result will be:

22552525 and 122221221 and 555554

Comment: @Manav in the database row one has 3 numbers (1,2,5), in row two it has 2 numbers (2,5) same with third row (1,2)

Comment: have you tried using a php script instead?

Comment: @Dave any hint which can clue me how to try that would be helpful right now!

Comment: @Manav you mean fetch all database and then displays those fulfilling condition using PHP? *Will that not take much time load data and then check each?* The data are in thousands!

Comment: yes, that's what i mean

Comment: your alternate is to test the row separately for every digit from 0 to 9 and then look for the ones with only two outcomes

Comment: @Manav any example related to the above database..

Comment: @xomunita edit your question and clarify what you want maybe with more or different sample data.

Comment: @forpas I added 2 more rows...

Comment: I think the op means to identify rows which use only two distinct digits. If so, my answer below should suffice @forpas

Comment: @Manav yes I think this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You test the column for every digit from 0 to 9, following which you add 1 to the count if it matches.

Thus, the `WHERE` clause returns rows only where the count is exactly 2

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM mytable
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%2%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%3%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%4%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%5%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%6%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%7%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%8%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%9%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN number LIKE '%0%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    = 2
```

Comment: Can I get a small explanation of CASE, THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +  ?

Comment: If the number is `LIKE '%1%'`, then 1 is added to the count, if not, the count is left unchanged (+0) and so on for all 10 digits

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the column can contain only numbers.
Apply twice `replace()` so to remove the 1st char and then the 1st char of the remaining string. 
If what is left is an empty string then this number contains only 2 different numbers.

```
select * from tablename
where 
  length(replace(number, left(number, 1), '')) > 0
  and              
  length(replace(
    replace(number, left(number, 1), ''),
    left(replace(number, left(number, 1), ''), 1),
    ''
  )) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iF6Yw7p377rmYqdiWchY11/0).
Results:

```
| number    |
| --------- |
| 22552525  |
| 122221221 |
| 555554    |
```